# SSRS Expression "Count of Days with No dissatisfied Customers" Cannot get it working

Tags: sql, reporting-services, expression, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-expression

I have to get a expression in my SSRS table that achieves the count of days with no dissatisfied customers.

Right now I have an expression like this:

`=RunningValue(IIF(Fields!SATISFACTION_LEVEL.Value <> "Dissatisfied",1,0),Sum, "DataSet1")`

This gives me the number of rows that contain a satisfaction level other than Dissatisfied.

[image: report design]

My issue is that I can't seem to get a count of days where there was no dissatisfied customer. I can't find a solution to counting the days. Essentially this is what it should do. If there was a record that day with a dissatisfied customer, don't count it. If there was no dissatisfied customers, tally it.

This will need to be done for the current year to date, and also for the year before.

I would really appreciate any help with this expression!

Thanks

UPDATE MORE INFO:

dataset structure is like this:

```
_______________________________________
| satisfaction_level     | Date       |
---------------------------------------    
| Satisfied              | 07/20/2020 |
| dissatisfied           | 07/20/2020 |
| Satisfied              | 07/20/2020 |
| Highly Satisfied       | 07/20/2020 |
| Satisfied              | 07/20/2020 |
| Satisfied              | 07/21/2020 |
| Satisfied              | 07/21/2020 |
| Highly Satisfied       | 07/21/2020 |
```

expected functionality - for the day of 7/20/2020 there was 1 dissatisfied customer (do not tally), for the day of 7/21/2020 there were NO dissatisfied customers (tally). Resulting in a total number of days where there were NO dissatisfied customers. I hope this helps further explain the outcome needed.

Comment: Can you show your report design including any row or column groups and show how they are grouped. Also show where in the report this expression has to be. The expression will probably depend your groups hence why I ask. Having said that, if you can change the dataset query I would do the work in SQL

Comment: @AlanSchofield I have included a link in the original post that will show you the report design. Right now there are no groups associated with the report. Any suggestions on how to do this in SQL? I've been struggling trying to get it set up to count the "days" rather than "records or rows". I have got it working in SQL to count the rows for each dissatisfied customer - but struggle to get it took look at this based on the day, and only count the day rather than the rows. (multiple rows are populated with the same date). Thanks!!

Comment: Can we assume that there are no Row Groups or Column Groups defined in your report as you have not shown any?

Comment: Actually, can you post a sample of data as it comes from your dataset and expected outcome based on htat sample data

Comment: @AlanSchofield I have updated the original post with an example of how the data gets presented, and what the outcome should be. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put SSRS to the side for now, the problem with counting days of anything is that its hard to count a row that is not there. For instance if I have a number of response records spread out over a week, but they only fall on 4 of the days, when we group by day, the query can only return results for the days that existed in the recordset:

```sql
DECLARE @Responses as Table 
(
    ENTRY_TIME DateTimeOffset, SATISFACTION_LEVEL VARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO @Responses
VALUES 
('2020-01-4', 'Dissatisfied'),
('2020-01-4', 'Dissatisfied'),
('2020-01-1', 'Satisfied'),
('2020-01-5', 'Dissatisfied'),
('2020-01-5', 'Satisfied'),
('2020-01-2', 'Dissatisfied')

SELECT 
  fn.DATE
  , DATENAME(WEEKDAY, fn.DATE) as [Day]
  , SUM(CASE SATISFACTION_LEVEL WHEN 'Dissatisfied' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Dissatisfied]
FROM @Responses
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(ENTRY_TIME as Date) as [DATE]) as fn
GROUP BY fn.DATE
ORDER BY fn.DATE
```

```
DATE       Day                            Dissatisfied
---------- ------------------------------ ------------
2020-01-01 Wednesday                      0
2020-01-02 Thursday                       1
2020-01-04 Saturday                       2
2020-01-05 Sunday                         1

(4 rows affected)
```

We can solve this problem by generating a series record set that we can join our real world data against that will ensure that we have a row for each day.

This can be achieved through the use of a recursive CTE, in the query below the grouped data result is joined to the series data, you could do this any number of different ways, you could even pivot the `SATISFACTION_LEVEL` column responses, this is just to illustrate
the technique of pre-processing the data in SQL before formatting it in an SSRS report:

```
DECLARE @From Date = '2019-12-30';
DECLARE @To Date = '2020-01-05';
;
WITH [Sequence] ([Date])
as
(
    SELECT @From
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date]) FROM [Sequence]
    WHERE [Date] < @To 
)
, [GroupedByDay]
as
(
    SELECT 
      fn.DATE
      , SUM(CASE SATISFACTION_LEVEL WHEN 'Dissatisfied' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Dissatisfied]
      , SUM(CASE SATISFACTION_LEVEL WHEN 'Satisfied' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Satisfied]
    FROM @Responses
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(ENTRY_TIME as Date) as [DATE]) as fn
    GROUP BY fn.DATE
)

SELECT 
    c.[Date]
    , DATENAME(WEEKDAY, c.[DATE]) as [Day]
    , ISNull([Dissatisfied],0) as [Dissatisfied]
    , ISNULL([Satisfied],0) as [Satisfied]
FROM [GroupedByDay] g
RIGHT OUTER JOIN [Sequence] c ON g.[DATE] = c.[Date]
ORDER BY c.[Date]
```

```
Date       Day                            Dissatisfied Satisfied
---------- ------------------------------ ------------ -----------
2019-12-30 Monday                         0            0
2019-12-31 Tuesday                        0            0
2020-01-01 Wednesday                      0            1
2020-01-02 Thursday                       1            0
2020-01-03 Friday                         0            0
2020-01-04 Saturday                       2            0
2020-01-05 Sunday                         1            1

(7 rows affected)
```

Without specific information about your schema and current query, that's about the best I can offer, however data by day should be more than enough for you group this into year on year results within SSRS...

- Or you could do it directly in SQL too if you want :)

---

#Update: Example where just the total count of days where there are no dissatisfied customers is returned:

```sql
DECLARE @From Date = '2019-12-30';
DECLARE @To Date = '2020-01-05';
;
WITH [Sequence] ([Date])
as
(
    SELECT @From
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date]) FROM [Sequence]
    WHERE [Date] < @To 
)
, [GroupedByDay]
as
(
    SELECT 
      fn.DATE
      , SUM(CASE SATISFACTION_LEVEL WHEN 'Dissatisfied' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Dissatisfied]
      , SUM(CASE SATISFACTION_LEVEL WHEN 'Satisfied' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Satisfied]
    FROM @Responses
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(ENTRY_TIME as Date) as [DATE]) as fn
    GROUP BY fn.DATE
)
, [InjectedMissingDays]
as
(
    SELECT 
        c.[Date]
        , DATENAME(WEEKDAY, c.[DATE]) as [Day]
        , ISNull([Dissatisfied],0) as [Dissatisfied]
        , ISNULL([Satisfied],0) as [Satisfied]
    FROM [GroupedByDay] g
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN [Sequence] c ON g.[DATE] = c.[Date]
)
--Overall 
SELECT COUNT(1) as [Days with No Dissatisfied Customers] FROM [InjectedMissingDays] WHERE Dissatisfied = 0
```

```
Days with No Dissatisfied Customers
-----------------------------------
4

(1 row affected)
```

Comment: This is a great explanation, and I appreciate you taking the time to explain this! I think that this could work. I will work on implementing this with my current query and let you know if I get it working. Thanks you for the help!